# Powershell - How to read EventData part of the XML

Tags: xml, powershell, event-viewer

I'm trying to figure it out how to read Event ID 1085 in Event Viewer - Details - EventData - DCName

[Link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kaVI.png)

I can read from the System part of the XML but I cannot figure out how to read from EventData

So far I have

```
  $filter = @{
     LogName = 'System'
     ID=1085
}
[xml[]]$xml = Get-WinEvent -filterHashTable $filter -MaxEvents 10 -ComputerName SERVER | %{$_.ToXml()}
$events = $xml | Select-Xml '//x:Event' -Namespace @{ x = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node

$events.System.Computer <# -- This works #>
$events.EventData.DCName <# -- This is not working #>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the `DCName`, you have to dig a little deeper in the XML:

```
$result = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName = 'System'; ID=1085} -MaxEvents 10 -ComputerName SERVER | ForEach-Object {
    # convert the event to XML and grab the Event node
    $eventXml = ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event

    # output a PsCustomObject to collect $result
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Computer  = $eventXml.System.Computer
        DCName    = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'DCNAME' }).'#text'
    }
}

# output on screen
$result
```

<sup>`$eventXml.EventData.Data` returns an array of nodes and you are interested in the one that has `DCName` in its Name attribute, so we need to filter with a `Where-Object` clause</sup>